# Extracting value(s) from json array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

My cart store orders in json_encode array into database. Is it possible to extract the total price from this array.. If there are 4 products I want to extract sum of all five prices?

Here is example of the array

```
{"73":{
     "title":"Test",
     "description":"",
     "quantity":1,
     "image":"",
     "price":90},
  "66":{
     "title":"Title",
     "description":"",
     "quantity":1,
     "image":"",
     "price":80},
  "shipping":{"
         quantity":1,
         "image":"",
         "description":"",
         "title":"Free Delivery",
         "price":0
  }
}
```

I want to extract all `price` fields and shwo the sum of them on the page.

edit: This is the array which I get

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
    (
        [title] => Test
        [description] => Test
        [quantity] => 1
        [image] => 
        [price] => 2
    )

    [6] => Array
    (
        [title] => Test
        [description] => Test
        [quantity] => 1
        [image] => 
        [price] => 12
    )

    [shipping] => Array
    (
        [quantity] => 1
        [image] => 
        [description] => 
        [title] => 
        [price] => 51
    )

)
```

Comment: decode the json to array first $new_array = json_decode($price_array,true);  then sum it

Comment: `<?php $data =json_decode($json_variable,true);echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);` now this printed array will let you know how to get desired data.

Comment: your json data is not valid http://php.fnlist.com/php/json_decode

Comment: your  json data is not valid check:- http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Anant it is not full json.

Comment: @Garg  then `$price = array_column($data, "price"); echo $total_amount = array_sum($price);`

Comment: foreach($array as $row) {  $total+=$row['price']; }  echo $total;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a **JSON**. It needs to be converted to **array** first.
>
> And then, you
> can use array function [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)  to retrieve all "price"
> values and apply [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to calculate the total price on this array.

```
// Assuming $data is the JSON.

$data  = json_decode($data, true); 
$price = array_sum(array_column($data, "price"));
```

Comment: his json data is not valid check:- http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I have uploaded what array looks like

Comment: In that case, just follow the second line. It should give you your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your json data is not valid

but i give the steps .how to sum the price

1)Decode the json to array first

2)then extract the price column by array_column function

3)then sum it using array_sum function

```
<?php $data =json_decode($json_variable,true);echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);

$price = array_column($data, "price"); 

echo $total_amount = array_sum($price);
```